# Why does my altered tkinter widget not place correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im creating a user management system that allows the admin to create user / employee accounts. When using the default tkinter "Entry" widget it places correctly. [correct placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h0qZ.png)

However when i use my version of the tk entry (LabeledEntry), it places like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7cdD.png)

this is the code for my altered entry widget:

```
class LabeledEntry(tk.Entry): #creates a version of the tkEntry widget that allows for "ghost" text to be within the entry field.
    def __init__(self, master=None, label = ""): #which instructs the user on what to enter in the field.
        tk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.label = label
        self.on_exit()
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_exit)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_entry)


    def on_entry(self, event=None):
        if self.get() == self.label: #checks if the given label is present
            self.delete(0, tk.END)  #If the text field of the entry is the same as the label, it is deleted to allow for user input
            self.configure(fg = "black") #sets the text color to black

    def on_exit(self, event=None):
        if not self.get(): #checks if user entered anything into the entry when clicked into it.
            self.insert(0, self.label) #If they did not, sets the text to the original label
            self.configure(fg = "grey") #and changes the color of the text to grey.
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing `master` to the superclass ctor, which is probably part of the issue:

```
class LabeledEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, label = ""):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        # ...
```

Comment: `super().__init__()` without passing master.